# My form doesn't submit in livewire project

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-livewire, livewires

I'm learning Livewire framework by an online course and in order to learning I created a test project.

in a part of this project I've a form that doesn't submit and the view refreshes but apparently there is nothing wrong with codes .

and it's necessarily that I point  after clicking the submit button and refreshing ' a ? add to URL.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth?

My form:

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="register">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
            </div>
        <input wire:model.lazy='name' class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" type="text">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
            </div>
        <input wire:model.lazy='email' class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" type="email">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->

    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input wire:model.lazy='password' class="form-control" placeholder="Create password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span>
        </div>
        <input wire:model.lazy='ConfirmPassword' class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password">
    </div> <!-- form-group// -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >
            create account
            <div wire:loading>
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>

            </div>

        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My component:

```php
class Register extends Component
{
    public $name,$email,$password,$ConfirmPassword;

    public function register(){
        dd('dul');
        $this->validate([
            'name'=>'required|string',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password'=>'required|string|min:8|same:ConfirmPassword',
        ]);

        User::create([
            'user'=>$this->name,
            'email'=>$this->email,
            'password'=>Hash::make($this->password),
        ]);

        session()->flash('success','registration done successfuly');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.register');
    }
}
```

My routes:

```php
<?php

    use App\Http\Livewire\Post\Index as INdexPost;
    use App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Index as IndexAuth;
    use App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Register ;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
    
    Route::get('/post', IndexPost::class);

    Route::get('/auth', IndexAuth::class);
```

Comment: this code in blade is wrapped in a root div container?

Comment: Sounds like Livewire isn't loaded properly. Have you added `@livewireScripts` to your layout? If yes, try `php artisan optimize`. The form should not submit like that with Livewire with the prevent modifier

Comment: Are there any errors in the console (from inspect element)? As Qirel pointed out, sounds like Livewire isn't properly initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Check your in blade root element, If there is more than one root element, post method instead of get method works.
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#root-element-issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).